# Lenovo M30-70 Disable Moving on Clickpad area

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

Really frustrated with the Laptop I have bought, it's a Lenovo M30-70 with Windows 7 professional.  It has the synaptics touchpad driver.

What annoys me is the whole click pad, I get very frustrated when I'm trying to click on the left mouse button, but it also senses movement and not just clicks.

Is there anyway I could stop the touchpad from moving when my finger is on the clicking area of the touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

Install new Synaptics driver. Problem solved. I have the same model and after update it works like charm.

Comment: Hi there, when was this driver released?  I haven't tried this for a few months?